# Real Analysis Question about Taylor's Thm & High order derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

The question is:

Let $I$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ be an open interval and let $f\colon I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $I$, and suppose $f''(a)$ exists at $a\in I$. Show that

$f''(a)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}$

Give an example where this limit exists, but the function does not have a second derivative at a.

I know that since $f''(a)$ exists, $f'(a)$ exists. but how does Taylor's Thm. come into this? Could someone help me out with the solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$
f(a+h) = f(a) + Df(a)h + \frac{1}{2}D^2 f(a)(1+o(1))h^2
$$
where $o(1) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$. Similarly for $f(a-h)$. Now plug into your ratio and let $h\to 0$.

Comment: What is this $o(1)$ value? I get that it must be between $a+h$ and $a$ though right?

Comment: $o(1)$ is a generic quantity (i.e. a function) that tends to zero as $h \to 0$. It is a classical Landau symbol.